# DirectX 10/11 Constant buffer contents not coming through

Tags: c++, directx-11, directx-10

I made a constant buffer defined as

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer : register(b1) {
float4x4 aMatrixTransforms[24];
float aMatrixWeights[24];
uint UsedMatrices;
float3 Unused;  
}
```

in HLSL and

```
struct stMBuffer {
D3DXMATRIX aMatrixTransforms[24];
float aMatrixWeights[24];
unsigned int UsedMatrices;
D3DXVECTOR3 Unused;
};
```

in c++

Now all of the matrices get delivered successfully as well as the first 5 elements of aMatrixWeights array but after that nothing its just 0. Anybody know whats going on? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check size of the buffer you're creating. Also you can use debug layer - it will show you wanrings for this case.

Comment: the size is fine, turns out hlsl expects all elements of the struct to come through as 16 byte float4's and the remaining data does get transferred, it just gets lost in the wasteland between array elements which even though have data for only 1 float arrive as xyzw floats. So.. is there any way to get around the 16 byte packing?

Comment: That's odd - have you checked in PIX what's actually coming to the buffer?